# Azure Application Insight. Custom attribute length restriction

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, custom-dimensions

I'm using `Azure` `App Insight` as a logging tool and store log data by the following code:

```
    private void SendTrace(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        loggingEvent.GetProperties();
        string message = "TestMessage";

        var trace = new TraceTelemetry(message)
        {
            SeverityLevel = SeverityLevel.Information
        };

        trace.Properties.Add("TestKey", "TestValue");
        var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
        telemetryClient.Context.InstrumentationKey = this.InstrumentationKey;
        telemetryClient.Track(trace);
    }
```

everything works well. I see logged record in `App insight` as well as in `App insight analytics` (in `trace` table). My *custom attributes* are written in special app insight row section - `customDimensions`. For example, the above code will add new attribute with *"TestKey"* key and "*TestValue"* value into `customDimensions` section.

But when I try to write some big text (for example `JSON` document with more then 15k letters) I still can do it without any exceptions, but the writable text will be cut off after some document length. As the result, the custom attribute value in `customDimensions` section will be cropped too and will have only first part of document.
As I understand there is the restriction for max text length which is allowed to be written in app insight custom attribute.

Could someone know how can I get around with this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `message` has the highest allowed limit of 32768. For items in the property collection, value has max limit of 8192.

So you can try one of the following options:

1. Use message field to the fullest by putting the big text there.
2. Split the data into multiple, and add to properties collection separately.

   eg:

   trace.Properties.Add("key_part1", "Bigtext1_upto8192");

   trace.Properties.Add("key_part2", "Bigtext2_upto8192");

Reference: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/includes/application-insights-limits.md

Comment: Is it possible to increase the length of the property collection

Comment: no, as they are enforced in backend and changes to the limits are unlikely to be entertained.

Comment: How would chunking these logs work when using `logging` in a Python Azure Function? Today, my logs are created using `logging.info()` within the Function. App Insights logs are truncated when the Function runs large, multi-part uploads to a web service. I can't see the end of the log (the "Success" message).

Comment: Another question: If I create App Insights alerts on one of these log messages, but the message is truncated, will the alert fire? My guess is no.