# Does Azure Application Insights have a max log length?

Tags: python, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer

I have an Azure Function (Python) tied to an App Insights instance. The Function downloads large blobs from Azure Storage for processing. The `BlobClient` makes **numerous** calls to the blob container as part of loading into memory.

**A file of ~2GB results in an App Insights log that is truncated (the last message in the log should be `### File Successfully Processed ###`):**

[image]

**The Kusto query is:**

```
union traces
| union exceptions
| where timestamp > ago(30d)
| where operation_Id == 'bigGUID'
| where customDimensions['InvocationId'] == 'bigGUID2'
| order by timestamp asc
| project timestamp, message = iff(message != '', message, iff(innermostMessage != '', innermostMessage, customDimensions.['prop__{OriginalFormat}'])), logLevel = customDimensions.['LogLevel']
```

**Is there a limit to App Insights log length for a single event?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's a max length.
Please find the answer here:

[Azure Application Insight. Custom attribute length restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446441/azure-application-insight-custom-attribute-length-restriction)

> The message has the highest allowed limit of 32768. For items in the property collection ,value has max limit of 8192.
> Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/EndpointSpecs/Schemas/Bond/MessageData.bond