# Can I increase the size of the column "Statement" in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure, logging, analytics, truncate

I have a KLOG statement used to extract some data from Azure Log Analytics. My problem is related to the fact that Azure Log Analytics seems to truncate the SQL statements longer than 4000 characters. For the audited server, I have more queries written by the users longer than 4000 characters. Can I increase the size of the column "Statement" somehow?

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Can I increase the size of the column "Statement" somehow?

Azure has a ***limitation*** of collecting log messages size.

If you want to add a custom property message with large no of length you can use the **[trackTrace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-trace-telemetry)**. It has the capacity to have max length up to ***8192*** characters.

```cs
# it will add more than 4000 character in AI Logs
 telemetryClient.TrackTrace(<telemetry with more than 4000 character >);
```

The highest max allowed message limit is ***32768*** characters for items in the property collection have limit of ***8192***. **(Max key length 150 value length 8192 characters)**

Refer [MS-DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model) for length limits of Application Insights Data model with respective to the type of telemetry.

#### Reference

- Follow the [Steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51446996/15997690) given by @cijothomas to add large length of message (more than 8K) to application Insights