# Azure AppInsight - Where is my custom attributes?

Tags: .net, azure, open-telemetry, appinsights

I am using OpenTelemetry, and trying to add a custom attribute to the current Span, and I can see the attribute (user.name, user.role) is showing as part of the trace:

```
// This is a sample trace coming from console exporter
Activity.TraceId:            1be70cf887cbde79d34d55e79642a9ee
Activity.SpanId:             4a40500a30985ff2
// Yada yada
Activity.Tags:
    net.host.name: localhost
    net.host.port: 7253
    // The next 2 are my custom attributes
    user.name: Ahamat, Farid
    user.role: Guest, Officer
    http.status_code: 200
Resource associated with Activity:
    // Yada yada
```

But I could not find out how to see this custom attribute in Azure App Insight. Anybody knows?

It must be stressed here that I'm using **OpenTelemetry**. I'm **NOT** using AppInsight SDK.

Comment: can you please share the code which you have tried?

Comment: This is not about code. This is about trying to find out how/where does AppInsight shows the custom attribute that I've created.

Comment: got your point, just for conformation have you configured custom attributes in local?

Comment: Yes. The trace does show the custom attributes. The one I showed above: that's my generated trace, it have my attributes.

Answer (score 1):

- using Azure Application Insight. Custom  [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51446441/azure-application-insight-custom-attribute-length-restriction#:%7E:text=My%20custom%20attributes%20are%20written%20in,special%20app%20insight%20row%20section%20-%20customDimensions.)  and Querying custom data in Application  [Insights](https://perfp.github.io/azure/2018/05/22/Querying-Custom-Data-AppInsights.html)
- Code taken from reference  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/observability-with-otel)

Here is way i added custom attributes .
[image]

- Logs of Custom attribes are found by requests query
- In application Insights, search for  logs, In Logs run `requests`

[image]

- Also can be found at the Transaction search at the request End to end transaction details
- You can find your attribute details with respective to your triggered time intervals.

[image]